# That- Clauses as Adjective Complements – How Do They Modify the Adjective?

Tags: adjectives, complements, noun-clause

Researching adjective complements, I have found the use of that- clauses quite jarring. The [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adjective-Complements.htm) lists the different types of adjective complements — prepositional phrases, infinitive phrases, and noun clauses — and I can't grasp how noun clauses (which seem to always be that- clauses) work in this context.

Both the prepositional and infinitive complements appear to be acting adverbially.

> I am perfectly content on my own

> I’m very happy to know you!

However, noun clauses can't suddenly become adverbial. The justification of this seems to be that it describes/justifies the adjective, but this is the only example I can think of outside of a subject complement and an object complement that does this.

Could someone explain the rational behind this (if there is one)? Also, could someone perhaps provide an example of a different complement acting similarly (discounting subject complements and object complements — if possible) to show if there are any other sentences where the complement doesn't directly modify something?

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. Forget the term 'noun clause'; there's no such thing. Nouns are nouns and clauses are clauses. The so-called _that_ clauses are not nouns but content clauses, whose function is that of subject or complement of some verb, noun or adjective. And complements are not modifiers -- that's an entirely different function. This is a big topic, so I suggest you get yourself a decent modern grammar book.

Comment: @BillJ For clarity, is this an opinion or objective fact? Having started to educate myself about the nuances of grammar, I have noticed that a lot of these statements are often a matter of perspective. There are many articles dedicated to noun clauses, so would you say they're outdated?

Comment: You may find this useful: [link](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/CGELtheory.pdf) Reference to 'noun clauses' is made on pages 8-11.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for this. The traditional classification does seem quite limited, which explains my confusion. I'm interested to hear a counterargument from someone who advocates the alternative approach.